# Cascade delete on delete of parent record (Managed Package)

Tags: managed-package, lookup, configuration

Here's my object model:

Student__c looks up **(not a M-D)** to Teacher__c.

On delete of Teacher__c I want all its child Student__c records to be deleted.
I'm trying to avoid any custom development i.e.,Trigger on Teacher__c.

I understand that there's an option on lookup field (marked in red) that needs to be enabled by Salesforce.com for your org.

[image]

Is there any other way to do this?
**If I have this option enabled in my org, will this work in a managed package that I'm developing?**

Comment: Did you try a Flow or a Process Builder?

Comment: I specifically want to use this option.

Comment: Your question is not clear - this should work on any object lookup field that you are using. If this object and fields are inside your managed package - this would work also for all the orgs that installed your package